# pipenv ошибка при установке пакета (locking failed)

Tags: python, django

Суть проблемы: изучаю Django, при установке пакета командой:

```
pipenv install django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
```

вылетает вот такая ошибка:

```
Installing django-crispy-forms…
Adding django-crispy-forms to Pipfile's [dev-packages]…

Installation Succeeded

Pipfile.lock (11da7f) out of date, updating to (30ae14)…

Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…

Success!

Locking [packages] dependencies…

Locking Failed!

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "c:/users/admin.lib/appdata/local/programs/python/python37-32/lib/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\admin.LIB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\admin.LIB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "C:\Users\admin.LIB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 395, in resolve

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches bootstrap

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found

[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.

 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.

  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches bootstrap

No versions found
Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
```

Точно такая же ошибка вылетала при попытке установить gunicorn в прошлом проекте. Вылечил просто создав проект заново, но это не дело, если каждый раз при такой ошибке надо пересобирать проект. Пожалуйста объясните в чем причина и как это лечится, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующим способом: удалил pipfile и pipfile.lock, вышел из pipenv с помощью команды exit. Потом пересоздал файлы с помощью pipenv install django==2.1, потом добавил зависимость pipenv install dgango-crispy-forms==1.7.2 Пакет установился, все работает.

Правда причина ошибки таки не понятна. Если кто знает - пожалуйста напишите ИЗ-ЗА ЧЕГО она вообще возникает. Спасибо.